# Blazor server app login.microsoftonline.com works fine from localhost but fails when deployed to Azure App Services

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cors, microsoft-graph-api

Blazor server app .NET 7 utilizing Microsoft identity and MS Graph Authenticates against Azure Ad and MSGraph from localhost but fails when deployed to Azure App Services with CORS Error. Have attempted multiple code changes to correct Cors errors to no avail. It appears that the error occurs when the call to login.microsoft.com.

Added `AspNetCore.Cors` package. Modified `Program.cs` and defined `AllowedOrigins` in `appsettings.Json`. Added Client Secret to `appsettings.json`.

Modified Azure App Registration Redirect URI's adding localhost and azure websites. Headers to login.microsoft.com from azure returns a 200 response from GET method but fails due to Cors.

Comment: Could you please share the error message.

Comment: If Cors is not working from `appsettings.json` file , add allow cors (AddCors) in program.cs file and check.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Blazor Server app with Authentication Type as `Microsoft Identity Platform`.

[image]

- Added the `Microsoft Graph Permissions`  from Visual Studio and Published the App.

[image]

- I got the below error with the status code 200.

[image]

[image]

- In the deployed Application  `site\wwwroot\` => in `web.config`, change the `stdoutLogEnabled="false"` to `true`.
- Now run the Application, a new log file will be created in the `C:\home\LogFiles>` path.

[image]

- We can get the detailed error in the log file.
- My error was, I missed the Client Secret value in the `appsettings.json` file.
- Added the client Secret Value and re-deployed the application.

***Output:***

[image]

- Add the MS Graph permissions in the registered App.

[image]

- Make sure the platform is Web.

[image]

***`appsettings.json` file:***

```cs
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "****.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "********",
    "ClientId": "********",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "********",
    "ClientCertificates": []
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://****.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  }
}
```

***Program.cs***

```cs
using BlazorApp1.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{ 
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});


builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

--------
```